# my device shows briefly under adb devices then disappears

Tags: rooting, adb, nexus-5

I got a (rooted) nexus 5 (with twrp custom recovery), and I develop on it using android studio 2.0. Recently when I type in adb devices, it shows my device for a couple of seconds then it vanishes! ie

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
03a3d66d0a4e64bd    device

$ adb devices
List of devices attached
03a3d66d0a4e64bd    device

$ adb devices
List of devices attached

$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

i tried everything:

- changing usb port
- `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`
- restarting phone
- installing android 6.0.1 update..

any ideas?

this is my adb version:

```
$adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
Revision 09a0d98bebce-android
```

Comment: Can you try with a different USB cable or altogether in a different PC with both same and different USB cable?

Comment: @Firelord it's inexplicable.. sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.. i'm ok with that but i would like to know a way to debug and understand why

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem recently. I plugged the phone directly into the laptop instead of via a USB Docking station. Solved the problem. I have no idea why it does it.